# sending job via ssh in python

Tags: python, ssh, nvidia

I have to run a script on several machines in a compute cluster using SSH. But before I run the script I have to log in into a node in the cluster using `ssh`, and then use `nvidia-smi` to check which GPU is free (as there is no job-scheduler in place at the moment). Each node has several GPUs. So I typically access, say GPU1, by issuing `ssh gpu1`...followed by `nvidia-smi` which just outputs a list of gpus and processes and utilization of each gpu.

I need to automate all this. That is, say we have 4 GPUs : gpu1...gpu4.
I want to be able to ssh into each of these, check their utlization, then run a python script `run_test.py -arg1` on the gpu that is free.

How can I write a python script that can do all these ?

I'm new to Python so need some help pls...

Comment: Sort of a tall order, but here's a start, https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/pxssh.html This is a nice way to run ssh commands in python.

Comment: Thanks Jacob. It takes me one step further to finding a solution!